# GIT appears to ignore my ssh config file

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I am behind a proxy so I decided to use corkscrew and an ssh config file to connect to bitbucket.

My `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  Hostname altssh.bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew <proxy_url> <proxy_port> %h %p
  Port 443
```

Clear enough, I define my proxy settings and tunnel my ssh connection through https on port 443.

It appears to work ok when I test `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org`
Here is the full verbose output showing a successful connection:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/corkscrew <proxy_url> <proxy_port> altssh.bitbucket.org 443 ~/.ssh/auth
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1001
debug1: identity file /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.268-723a194 app-132
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.268-723a194 app-132
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host '[altssh.bitbucket.org]:443' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sierraromeo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to altssh.bitbucket.org (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
logged in as SierraRomeo.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 4048, received 1984 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 18748.6, received 9189.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

But when I simply run a `git pull` (or any other git command) it appears the config file is ignored.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

My `project/.git/config` file has been checked and looks ok:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:path/to/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I'm probably missing something here but cannot see what.

Why is ssh connecting when doing `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` and failing instantly when using a `git <command>`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

(I'm running GIT 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: Run the `git pull` with `GIT_SSH="ssh -vvv"` to get the same output as above to check why it is failing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the problem. If I only knew this before. The issue was that for an obscure reason, `git pull` ran as root so yes, my user specific ssh config file was ignored. As simple as that.

Comment: How did you solve this and stop git from using root?

Comment: I seem to waste about an hour doing this to myself about twice a year! ;-( Make sure you are cloning using the git .ssh repo location `git@github.com:<repo>/<user>.git`, not the https location `https://github.com/<repo>/<repo>.git`, if you want ssh to work!